# Azure - How to confirm NIC is configured correctly?

Tags: azure, nic, azure-load-balancer

I have an Azure Load Balancer which health probes 2 NICs, with a VM attached to each NIC.

```
Azure LB -> NIC1 -> VM1
         -> NIC2 -> VM2
```

The LB health probes (which hit the NICs on TCP port 443) are failing, and I'm struggling to understand why.

I can successfully connect to both VMs just fine using: *Test-NetConnection IP -port 443*

Therefore I can only assume the NICs themselves are the problem, since the same test fails for their private IP. How can I go about diagnosing this to confirm that's the case? In the Azure portal my NIC is clearly attached to my VM, what exactly else could go wrong with a NIC?

Comment: that makes no sense, you probably do not have anything listening on those ports

Comment: How did you check LB health probes failing? Do you use `Test-NetConnection IP -port 443` via load balancer frontend public IP? Please note that `All Load Balancer health probes originate from the IP address 168.63.129.16 as their source`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-custom-probe-overview#probesource.

Comment: Do you use the VM itself public IP or LB frontend IP to test via `Test-NetConnection IP -port 443`? What do you mean `since the same test fails for their private IP`?  Could you elaborate it more details?